# Can a C152 land VFR in Miami International Airport (KMIA)?

Tags: landing, cessna-152

I know that it is a Class B airspace and VFR aircraft should request clearance at least 1 hour in advance before entering. The question is more related to MIA operations restrictions due to airliners.

It is possible to land with a C152 there, apart from being above VMC weather minimums (3 SM visibility and clear of clouds) and having 2-ways radio and transponder Mode C? How much is the landing fee? How can I gather all the information for GA and light ACFT operations in MIA?

Comment: [I don't see why not...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxjjH27FJ5c) They might even make the airliner slow down for you.

Answer (score 3):

Sure can if your C-152 is equipped with at least a two way VHF radio and a transponder with altitude reporting capability.  And you hold at least a PPL with current medical or are a student pilot with current medical and have a logbook endorsement from a CFI to fly there.

According to the A/FD entry for KMIA, all GA arrivals should file request a clearance at least three hours in advance of their arrival (this three hour notification is only for international GA flights requiring customs).

As with flying into any Class B airport, you will have to be on top of your game and able to quickly and accurately comply with ATC instructions.  Have all you charts and plates ready to go, especially taxi diagrams and frequencies.  Expect taxiing delays and instructions.  Wake Turbulence avoidance procedures should be used and anticipated.